# set exact value after divide it with some value

Tags: python-3.x

Need value exact 1 when I divide 3/4. so, how to rounded with exact value in python. It should be 1 not even 1.0 or 0.75 or 0

```
print(3/4) = 0.75
print(3//4) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the built-in [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) with no precision digits:

```
>>> print(round(3/4))
1
```